# run shell commands through os module and subprocess module, one works and the other one does not work

Tags: shell, python

I'm learning how to run shell commands through the os module and the subprocess module. The following is my code.

```
from subprocess import call
call('/usr/lib/mailman/bin/find_member -w user_email')
import os
os.system('/usr/lib/mailman/bin/find_member -w user_email')
```

The second one works very well, while on the other hand, the first one does not work, and I got the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fabfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    call('/usr/lib/mailman/bin/find_member -w user_email')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
    p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I thought those two methods have the same effect. Could you point to me what's the possible errors here? Many thanks.

Comment: Try: `call('/usr/lib/mailman/bin/find_member -w user_email', shell=True)` or, better yet: `call(['/usr/lib/mailman/bin/find_member', '-w', 'user_email'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference between the two is documented ([Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.system))

> os.system(command)
>
> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.

While [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) looks like:

> subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
>
> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

To make `subprocess.call()` behave the same as `os.system()` you need to pass `shell=True`.  So something like:

```
from subprocess import call
call('/usr/lib/mailman/bin/find_member -w user_email', shell=True)
```